# podman/docker cannot reach exposed ports

Tags: ubuntu, docker, podman

We recently upgraded our infrastructure to the new Strato KVM VPS. After we had set up our dockerized services we noticed that none of our services are reachable through their defined ports. Neither from localhost nor from external. This happens with both podman and docker. Our images are working correctly. If we use the `--net host` flag everything works fine and can be reached but thats not what we want and should not be necessary. If you need more information feel free to ask.

We are grateful for any help.

Additional information:
`os: ubuntu 22.04`
`podman: 3.4.4`
`cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/forwarding 1`
`cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward 1`
`cat /sys/module/ipv6/parameters/disable 0`

Interfaces (podman)

```
3: cni-podman0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: veth0b47ca4c@if3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xxbrd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netns cni-3b592073-b05b-6473-f81c-23018ac36950
    inet6 xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Podman inspect

```
[
    {
        "Id": "c999130c8645cbc407c1df1df03e185884b5cbe6dacb1088567f89191ae9aad2",
        "Created": "2023-06-23T07:40:22.316742043Z",
        "Path": "docker-entrypoint.sh",
        "Args": [
            "node",
            "server.js"
        ],
        "State": {
            "OciVersion": "1.0.2-dev",
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 13418,
            "ConmonPid": 13415,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2023-06-23T07:40:22.546936291Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
            "Healthcheck": {
                "Status": "",
                "FailingStreak": 0,
                "Log": null
            },
            "CgroupPath": "/machine.slice/libpod-c999130c8645cbc407c1df1df03e185884b5cbe6dacb1088567f89191ae9aad2.scope"
        },
        "Image": "71c248232ca5eaf774116371245d524516a6fcf46abd2f99fe2c4b721eed77c9",
        "ImageName": "nextjs-docker-test:main",
        "Rootfs": "",
        "Pod": "",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/run/containers/storage/overlay-containers/c999130c8645cbc407c1df1df03e185884b5cbe6dacb1088567f89191ae9aad2/userdata/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/run/containers/storage/overlay-containers/c999130c8645cbc407c1df1df03e185884b5cbe6dacb1088567f89191ae9aad2/userdata/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/run/containers/storage/overlay-containers/c999130c8645cbc407c1df1df03e185884b5cbe6dacb1088567f89191ae9aad2/userdata/hosts",
        "StaticDir": "/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay-containers/c999130c8645cbc407c1df1df03e185884b5cbe6dacb1088567f89191ae9aad2/userdata",
        "OCIConfigPath": "/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay-containers/c999130c8645cbc407c1df1df03e185884b5cbe6dacb1088567f89191ae9aad2/userdata/config.json",
        "OCIRuntime": "crun",
        "ConmonPidFile": "/run/containers/storage/overlay-containers/c999130c8645cbc407c1df1df03e185884b5cbe6dacb1088567f89191ae9aad2/userdata/conmon.pid",
        "PidFile": "/run/containers/storage/overlay-containers/c999130c8645cbc407c1df1df03e185884b5cbe6dacb1088567f89191ae9aad2/userdata/pidfile",
        "Name": "nextjs-docker-test",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "overlay",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "containers-default-0.44.4",
        "EffectiveCaps": null,
        "BoundingCaps": [
            "CAP_CHOWN",
            "CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE",
            "CAP_FOWNER",
            "CAP_FSETID",
            "CAP_KILL",
            "CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE",
            "CAP_SETFCAP",
            "CAP_SETGID",
            "CAP_SETPCAP",
            "CAP_SETUID",
            "CAP_SYS_CHROOT"
        ],
        "ExecIDs": [],
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Name": "overlay",
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/ef964276b39d5c231f0bc8930d37d390edfc0ac85979882c76ea8f11afb2ed97/diff:/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/2f321646b65a22c485d662a660fe1d4ca0af09e05bd69e886264db5375f4b592/diff:/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/4ed7439a59a6561844e6e59ae14b20f3a9175cce3cc8973714f8816da94422e2/diff:/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/fb3e6189305043478f27f86f34cfdcd77a0913bf31adea6b44c7d5c3252ed5bb/diff:/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/dabf1d2858b89bf69c1b98e85b661abe837a7af196cf9f655426a12a32147e58/diff:/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/027e7695d766dfd80b221dd37accdea27dd790ebe9ed059c52a8929fed1f9b94/diff:/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/406c6f7fd87fd2cfd1f33236a8cb68449860265a170ea8a2713625809ec9355e/diff:/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/739b7c1d47c50966c7056fa3cd650cf2c4acff257645c3dc6bdc0be4b3eb53c3/diff:/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/58cafb3f4cd1cb8956b4a925072c958e57765037b7bc5d2e9b443530f7744600/diff:/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/408c359632854f654eb3648038eb6cc7508d9a102d6d233fc6db090ceff2e247/diff:/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/78a822fe2a2d2c84f3de4a403188c45f623017d6a4521d23047c9fbb0801794c/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/a0acea5314c51cd0e05a51f48204014e9368e01549ed6da4e81f17d140a06a8c/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/a0acea5314c51cd0e05a51f48204014e9368e01549ed6da4e81f17d140a06a8c/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/a0acea5314c51cd0e05a51f48204014e9368e01549ed6da4e81f17d140a06a8c/work"
            }
        },
        "Mounts": [],
        "Dependencies": [],
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "10.88.0.1",
            "IPAddress": "10.88.0.4",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "MacAddress": "xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx",
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "3000/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "3001"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/run/netns/cni-3b592073-b05b-6473-f81c-23018ac36950",
            "Networks": {
                "podman": {
                    "EndpointID": "",
                    "Gateway": "10.88.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "10.88.0.4",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx",
                    "NetworkID": "podman",
                    "DriverOpts": null,
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null
                }
            }
        },
        "ExitCommand": [
            "/usr/bin/podman",
            "--root",
            "/var/lib/containers/storage",
            "--runroot",
            "/run/containers/storage",
            "--log-level",
            "warning",
            "--cgroup-manager",
            "systemd",
            "--tmpdir",
            "/run/libpod",
            "--runtime",
            "crun",
            "--events-backend",
            "journald",
            "container",
            "cleanup",
            "c999130c8645cbc407c1df1df03e185884b5cbe6dacb1088567f89191ae9aad2"
        ],
        "Namespace": "",
        "IsInfra": false,
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "c999130c8645",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "nextjs",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "TERM=xterm",
                "container=podman",
                "NODE_VERSION=18.16.1",
                "YARN_VERSION=1.22.19",
                "NODE_ENV=production",
                "PORT=3000",
                "HOME=/home/nextjs",
                "HOSTNAME=c999130c8645"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "node",
                "server.js"
            ],
            "Image": "nextjs-docker-test:main",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "/app",
            "Entrypoint": "docker-entrypoint.sh",
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": null,
            "Annotations": {
                "io.container.manager": "libpod",
                "io.kubernetes.cri-o.Created": "2023-06-23T07:40:22.316742043Z",
                "io.kubernetes.cri-o.TTY": "false",
                "io.podman.annotations.autoremove": "FALSE",
                "io.podman.annotations.init": "FALSE",
                "io.podman.annotations.privileged": "FALSE",
                "io.podman.annotations.publish-all": "FALSE",
                "org.opencontainers.image.stopSignal": "15"
            },
            "StopSignal": 15,
            "CreateCommand": [
                "podman",
                "run",
                "-p",
                "3001:3000",
                "--network=bridge",
                "-d",
                "--restart",
                "unless-stopped",
                "--name",
                "nextjs-docker-test",
                "nextjs-docker-test:main"
            ],
            "Umask": "0022",
            "Timeout": 0,
            "StopTimeout": 10
        },
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": [],
            "CgroupManager": "systemd",
            "CgroupMode": "private",
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "journald",
                "Config": null,
                "Path": "",
                "Tag": "",
                "Size": "0B"
            },
            "NetworkMode": "bridge",
            "PortBindings": {
                "3000/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "3001"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "unless-stopped",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "CapAdd": [],
            "CapDrop": [
                "CAP_AUDIT_WRITE",
                "CAP_MKNOD",
                "CAP_NET_RAW"
            ],
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": [],
            "GroupAdd": [],
            "IpcMode": "private",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Cgroups": "default",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "private",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": [],
            "Tmpfs": {},
            "UTSMode": "private",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 65536000,
            "Runtime": "oci",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": [],
            "DiskQuota": 0,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": 0,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": 2048,
            "Ulimits": [
                {
                    "Name": "RLIMIT_NOFILE",
                    "Soft": 1048576,
                    "Hard": 1048576
                },
                {
                    "Name": "RLIMIT_NPROC",
                    "Soft": 4194304,
                    "Hard": 4194304
                }
            ],
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
            "CgroupConf": null
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long conversation with Strato, they admitted that, as stated in the more or less hidden FAQ, the VPS do not fully support Docker. The label "docker ready" only means that Docker could partially work. Docker works fine a slong as you use the `--net host` flag.